# Writing count sort and I figured I could nest a while loop in a for loop to copy the contents back to array. What is the time complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, counting-sort

I am trying to write count sort and I understand nesting loops could change the time complexity to O(n<sup>2</sup>) depending on the algorithm. So instead of writing two different for loops, one which writes to an output array and the other one copying the output array into the main array, I figured I could do a nested while loop inside a for loop to copy contents back into the array while decreasing the count.

The for loop takes n times the length of count storage, and then the while loop will depend if `count[i] > 0` else it will just iterate through the next index in the count array. I just need count sort to be in O(n) taking into consideration worst case time complexity. Here is my code below:

Say for example after getting the counts, count array will be this `[0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 5]`

Then I do this code segment to write back into the main array,

```
    int idx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        while (count[i] > 0) {
            arr[idx++] = i;
            count[i]--;
        }
    }
```

I just want to know the break down of the time complexity in this code segment and if the time complexity for this segment will ever become O(n<sup>2</sup>) or instead using two different for loops would be better to achieve O(n).

Comment: `O(m + n)`, where `m` is the maximum element size, and `n` is the number of elements. You visit each element of both arrays exactly once. It'd be easier to conceptualize if you rewrote the inner `while` to `for (int j = count[i]; j > 0; j--) {arr[idx++] = i}`.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to know! Thank you.

Comment: So as long as `m <= n` my overall time complexity would be O(n) right?

Comment: no, `O(m + n)`, because `m` and `n` are completely independent of each other, so you can't fold one into the other. You can still call this linear complexity, though.

Comment: It’s simpler and in most cases faster to use `for(int i = 0, idx = 0; i < count.length; i++) Arrays.fill(arr, idx, idx += count[i], i);`